# Laravel session cookie not encrypted when using AJAX

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm about to create a single-sign-on interface for my app. The other app sends an AJAX POST request and I authenticate the user and return a response. A session cookie is beeing set, but it is not encrypted.

The relevant Code

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
if ($user) {
  Auth::login($user);
  return response("OK", 200);
}
```

My 'api' part in Kernel.php

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
],
```

My route (no additional Middleware)

```
Route::post(
  '/auth-request', [
  'uses' => 'UserController@post_authenticateRequest',
  'as' => 'authrequest'
]);
```

The EncryptCookies class in Kernel.php doesn't seem to have any effect in the AJAX post request - but only for the session part. When I manually add a cookie like

```
response("OK", 200)->cookie("mysession", Session::getId(), 60);
```

it is encrypted!

When I completely remove EncryptCookies in Kernel.php for both "api" and "web" the created session from the AJAX request is loaded correctly - but without encryption anymore.

How do I get the AJAX session cookie beeing encrypted? Do I need any other Middleware?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: put `EncryptCookies` before `StartSession`?

Comment: @lagbox Oh man. I've done that allready but it didn't changed. But to check your advice I've placed it before all other definitions and hurray it's encrypted now! Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reading the comment from lagbox, I've tried several places for the EncryptCookies::class definition in my "api" part. I need to place it not only before StartSession but as the first element. And now it works!

My complete $middlewareGroups part in Kernel.php now looks like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\App::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    ],
];
```

Hope this is helpfull.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4.36 in this project

Comment: I found out that `EncryptCookies` should be loaded before the `throttle` middleware as well.