# Laravel creating non-encrypted cookie value on ajax response

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-5.7

I set a cookie on ajax response call like this:

`return response($response, 200)->cookie('xid', $token, 2*24*60);`

The above creates a cookie like this (which is the token value, raw, non-encrypted):
[image]

You can see this when running this code in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tid = "{{ Cookie::get('xid') }}";
        var tid = "{{ $_COOKIE['xid'] }}";
</script>
```

I get the following output:

[image]

If I check the "laravel_session" cookie instead, the output is correct (it's encrypted):
[image]

Any ideas why the `xid` cookie is not being encrypted? There are no exceptions in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding the EncryptCookie class in the api middlewaregroups in the Kernel as per [Laravel session cookie not encrypted when using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51375193/laravel-session-cookie-not-encrypted-when-using-ajax)